# dynamic payload processing in wso2 esb

Tags: dynamic, wso2, message, esb

I have dynamic payload coming into ESB proxy which need to be send to BAM server after parsing every individual elements (which could be nested too). This dynamic payload contains repeated complex type elements. How can I traverse it through as part of ESB sequence and give unique name for each repeated element dynamically and send it to BAM server ? e.g. Employee XML element is dynamic it can be repeated multiple times.

`<Request>
    <appName></appName>
    <Employee>
       <name></name>
       <age></age>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <name></name>
       <age></age>
       <Qualifications>
          <degree></degree>
          <year></year>
          <college></college>
       </Qualifications>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <name></name>
       <age></age>
    </Employee>
</Request>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood, you need to traverse through  elements and send them to BAM one by one.
You can use Iterator mediator for getting the elements one by one.[1]
Then you need to use payloadFactory mediator to add a unique id. For this you can add a new element inside . You can find samples for this by searching at the same Doc site[1].
You can also refer this blog[2] to understand payloadFactory more.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Iterate+Mediator

[2] http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2013/05/wso2-esb-payload-mediator-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for response. So if we iterate one by one and send it to BAM, than wouldn't it overwrite values under Cassandra stream. Say for first iteration it sends //Employee/name and for second iteration also it found same element with different value.